# Entity Framework Core and .NET Standard 2.0 - an inconsistent behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, vsto, .net-standard

**Environment**: `VS2019 - ver16.6`, `Windows 10 pro 1903`

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#other-target-frameworks) link from Microsoft team to create a `VS2019` solution with `.NET Standard 2.0` library project and a dummy `.NET Core Console` app as a startup project. In that solution, I also followed this [EF Core official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio) to create a `SQLite` db (called `MySQLiteDb.db`) that gets created in the root directory of dummy `.NET Core Console`.

Afterwards, I referenced that `.NET Standard` library in one of my `WPF Full Framework` project to perform some db operations. For that I copied `MySQLiteDb.db` from the above project into this `WPF` project and set its `Copy to output directory` action to `Copy if newer` with `Build Action` as `None`. Now, this `WPF Full Framework` app works fine and performs multiple db operation on `MySQLiteDb.db`.

But when I do the same as above on a [Microsoft VSTO Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) project by referencing the same `.NET Standard` library, I get an inconsistent behavior: For example, half of the time the app successfully  performs a data insert but about half of the time the app throws the following error on the data insert. And there is no data validation because this test db has three simple text columns with no unique keys/index etc. Question: Why this inconsistent behavior on `VSTO` project but not on `WPF` project while both are `.NET 4.8` projects. And how can the issue be resolved?

**Error**:

> Inner Exception 1: SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: MyTable'.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this inconsistent behavior on VSTO project but not on WPF project while both are .NET 4.8 projects.

You need to make sure the add-in is using the .net framework 4.0 runtime (CLR) which corresponds to the .net framework 4.8, not CLR 2.0. You can use a configuration file to specify the runtime version to use by the host application, see [Application Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-configuration-files) for more information on the `runtime` element.

Comment: Could you please provide a couple of more steps on how do I do that. First I thought of changing the `net framework` from 4.8 to 4.0. But, I think, that's not what you meant.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check at runtime which CLR and .Net framework is used? Is there any difference where it works and fails?

Comment: @EugenAstafiev After your comment, I observed that app is using CLR 4.0 in both cases failed or worked. One sample: `'WINWORD.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`

Comment: Take a look at the event viewer in Windows. Do you get any errors written there?

Comment: No errors shown there. In debug mode, I was able to add two records. Two clicks added two records. Third click threw the exact same error as shown in post above.